# Cannot read boolean value with TMemoryStream

Tags: delphi

I am trying to read a boolean value using a simple line piece of code like this: ReadBuffer(Result, 1).

After reading, Result is true. However

> Result:= not Result

will not 'switch' the value false.
I am doing obviously a basic mistake here.

Full code:

```
TYPE
  TCMemStream= class(TMemoryStream)
    public
     function  ReadBoolean: Boolean;
  end;


function TCMemStream.ReadBoolean: Boolean;
begin
 ReadBuffer(Result, 1);
 Result:= NOT Result;    <-------- after executing this line, Result has the same value
 Result:= false;      <----- this works
end;
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Valid values for a `Boolean` are 0 and 1. If you put a different value into a `Boolean` variable then future behaviour is undefined.

You should read into a byte variable `b` and assign `b <> 0` into the `Boolean`. Or sanitise by casting the byte to `ByteBool`. Or you may choose to validate the value read from the file and reject anything other than `0` and `1`.

Comment: Or use `ByteBool`, if appropriate.

Comment: ByteBool can also be used to sanitize the boolean, with a typecast.

Comment: Very nice/odd behavior I got using Result as buffer. I had no clue that it can behave that strange when loading binary data directly into a Boolean var. Indeed after loading data into a byte var, its value was 255 (representing true). So it seems that TRUE/FALSE is hold as $FF/$00 in a Boolean var. Thanks David for shedding some light into this.